# Word frequencies program that uses the a file

Tags: python

```
#alphabets.py
def remove_nonalphabet(msg):
    result = ""
    for char in msg:
        if char.isalpha():
            result += char
    return result
```

I'm trying to use the remove_nonalphabet function from the alphabet.py above in the program below to find the word frequencies while making it handle case-insensitive matching. I can't seem to get it to work. The words frequencies program is pulling the words from a ".txt" file that has the following words:
"One fish, Two fish, Red fish, Blue fish,
Black fish, Blue fish, Old fish, New fish.
This one has a littlecar.
This one has a little star.
Say! What a lot of fish there are.
Yes. Some are red, and some are blue."

I got the words_frequencies function but was not quite sure where to use remove_nonalphabets from the alphabets.py above without writing the remove_nonalphabet() function into the working file (is that possible?)

```
import alphabets
def word_frequencies(file_obj):
    # Make sure it can handle case-insensitive matching. 
    freq = {}
    for word in file_obj.split(" "):
        if word in freq:
            freq[word] += 1
        else:
            freq[word] = 1
    return freq 


# The main program.  Do not change it.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = input("Enter a filename: ")
    file_object = open(filename, "r")
    your_dictionary = word_frequencies(file_object)
    sorted_keys = sorted(your_dictionary.keys())
    for key in sorted_keys:
        print(key + ': ' + str(your_dictionary[key]))
    file_object.close()
```

Comment: Your function `remove_nonalphabet` does not make matching case-insensitive. It simply removes non-alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 1):

Start by converting the entire file content to lowercase. This avoids multiple calls to str.lower()

Rather than constructing strings by continually appending characters it's better to build a list (or generator as in this example) then join the contents.

Something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def remove_nonalphabet(w):
    return ''.join(c for c in w if c.isalpha())

def word_frequencies(f):
    return Counter(map(remove_nonalphabet, f.read().lower().split()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = input('Enter filename: ')
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for k, v in sorted(word_frequencies(infile).items()):
            print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

**Output:**

```
a: 3
and: 1
are: 3
black: 1
blue: 3
fish: 9
has: 2
little: 1
littlecar: 1
lot: 1
new: 1
of: 1
old: 1
one: 3
red: 2
say: 1
some: 2
star: 1
there: 1
this: 2
two: 1
what: 1
yes: 1
```

Comment: Great answer @OldBill, but you should have kept your earlier version as well, the `dict[k] = dict.get(k) + 1` is a nice pattern for when counting if people don't want the collections library (for whatever reason).

Comment: @bn_ln The Python pedants argue about that all the time. I sit on both sides of the fence. One strong argument is that beginners should be encouraged to utilise standard classes

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the case by reducing all words to lower case, and when you read the `file_obj` you should use the `read` method.  The first function probably isn't needed as it's very short, so maybe consider removing it.

```
def remove_nonalphabet(msg):
    return ''.join([char for char in msg if char.isalpha()]).lower()
    
def word_frequencies(file_obj):
    freqs = {}
    for word in file_obj.read().split():
        trimmed_word = remove_nonalphabet(word)
        if trimmed_word not in freqs:
             freqs[trimmed_word] = 0
        freqs[trimmed_word] += 1
    return freqs
```

Without the first function;

```
def word_frequencies(file_obj):
    freqs = {}
    for word in file_obj.read().split():
        trimmed_word = ''.join([char for char in word if char.isalpha()]).lower()
        if trimmed_word not in freqs:
             freqs[trimmed_word] = 0
        freqs[trimmed_word] += 1
    return freqs
```